# css how to remove the empty space at the left

Tags: html, css

This is a fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/jB9t7/

and this is the image
[image]

Please look that the checkboxes starts from the `middle` not from the left

#### how to remove the left space please

Comment: What you mean? I see just a switch starting from ~10px of the border, not from the middle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply have to remove the default `padding-left` that's automatically added to `ul` elements. Adding that style to your existing styles for the `ul`, you would get the following:

```
#campaignDiv ul {
    color: #fff;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-left:0;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jB9t7/16/)

Comment: Downvoter, instead of simply downvoting every single answer here, please explain why this answer is not right in your opinion

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but your answer to the question doesn't work

Comment: @Cheejyg he's asking to remove the space to the left, right? That's what I did.

Comment: you are the one man, it works. +1 and I will accept when the system allwo

Comment: @Joeytje50 yeah seems like I misinterpreted the question

Answer (score 1):

It comes from your absolute positioning of `#campaignDiv li label`

http://jsfiddle.net/Cheejyg/jB9t7/2/

```
#campaignDiv li label {
        left: 12px;
}
```

setting it to 5px seems about right

```
#campaignDiv li label {
        left: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Still the same, I changed to 5px and still the same

Comment: Weird, I did it and it worked for me, check my answer with image.

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli even in the demo? cause I don't see any left space here

Comment: @AliGajani well looks like we both misinterpreted the question? LOL.

Comment: Weird, it was natural for me to think that way lol :) no worries

Comment: @Cheejyg I am poor in english, it seems that you removed the left pading in the label not in the whole div. the selected answer did

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli yeah because your label was misaligned, so I thought that u were saying That **left space**

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

In your `left` position, You had put `12`, simply replace by `5` :)

```
#campaignDiv li label {
display: block;
width: 36px;/*52*/
height: 18px;/*22*/
border-radius: 50px;
-webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
-moz-transition: all .5s ease;
-o-transition: all .5s ease;
-ms-transition: all .5s ease;
transition: all .5s ease;
cursor: pointer;
position: absolute;
top: 4px;/*9*/
z-index: 1;
left: 5px;
background: #ddd;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5Zr85/)

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but your answer does lack an explanation of what you're actually doing here. If you'd add that, I assume the downvoter will remove his downvote.